# Get the date of a specific bar on TradingView Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I'm writing an indicator where I need to "anchor" it to a certain date of interest. Basically an anchored VWAP where I'm trying to automate finding easy areas of interest to "anchor" the indicator to.

Basically, I'm trying to get the Highest and Lowest value over a lookback period (say 365 in this example, and trying to "access" the date of that bar, so I can initialise t (time) as starting in that bar.

I can do this with individual inputs but unsure how to do it with accessing time/date information from previous bars. Thanks!

```
h1 = highest(high, 365)
time(h1) (?)  *this is wrong* 
start = t == time
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `highestbars()` for that, which returns the offset of the highest high. It returns a negative value, so we need to change its sign:

```
//@version=4
study("")
// Get bar index of highest high.
highIndex = -highestbars(high, 365)
// Get time at highest high.
t = time[highIndex]
plot(highIndex, "Index of highest high")
// Plot day of the month of highest high's bar.
plot(dayofmonth(t), "Day of the month", color.red)
```